# Haskell "Unresolved Overloading"

Tags: haskell

The following code to enumerate "backwards binary"

```
bin :: [Char] -> Int
bin a = temp (a, 1)
    where
        temp :: ([Char], Int) -> Int
        temp ([], n) = 0
        temp (('1':x), n) = temp(x, (n*2)) + 1*n
        temp (('0':x), n) = temp(x, (n*2))
```

produces the following error:

```
 TYPE - Unresolved Overloading
 *** Type       : Num [Char] => Int
 *** Expression : Bin 1001
```

Similar code worked fine when it was [Int] -> Int, I have no idea why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: the function looks fine but it seems you are using it wrong, next time try to put the usage of the function too

Comment: Oops, that would be Main> Bin 1001

Comment: no worries, just wanted to give you that hint so you can find help quicker ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the function with incorrect type, that is `Int` (`1001`) when it really epects `[Char]`, e.g. `bin ['1','0','0','1']`.

Comment: Or `bin "1001"`.